# Changing body background with CSS, using the same code on both pages but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have two HTML pages

*list.html*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>List</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {background-image:url('Judul.jpg');}
</style>
<body>
    <br></br>
    <a href="about.html" target="tengah" style="color:blue;margin-center:40px;font-family:Segoe UI;">Main page</a>
    <br></br>
    <a href="list.html" target="tengah" style="color:blue;margin-center:40px;font-family:Segoe UI;">About Us</a>
</body>
</html>
```

then the second one

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Elemental Website</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {background-image:url('Judul.jpg');}
</style>
<body>
    <h1 style="font-family:Segoe UI;60px;text-align:center;">Judul</h1>
    <pr></pr>
    <pr></pr>
    <table bordercolor=blue align=center border=1>
        <tr align=center height=25>
            <td><marquee>Welcome !</marquee></td>
            <td><marquee>Welcome !</marquee></td>
            <td><marquee>Welcome !</marquee></td>
            <td><marquee>Welcome !</marquee></td>
            <td><marquee>Welcome !</marquee></td>
            <td><marquee>Welcome !</marquee></td>
            <td><marquee>Welcome !</marquee></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h2 align=left font face=italic>
        <p style="font-size:14px">Current Resolution : 1920 x 1080</p>
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is simply change the second pages background with the CSS, but it doesn't load the background image, however it loads perfectly on the *list.html*.

So am I missing something?

Comment: Is the pages on same folder level ?

Comment: It's diffrent two page,used as IFrame on an _index.html_ but i tried the code above by open it separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to the background image not loading, I would assume that it is because the files are in two different folders, and the image is only in the first folder. If you move the file that isn't working correctly into the same folder as the one that is, the image should work. Alternatively fix the path to the image on the page that isn't working.

Aside from the image not loading, there are quite a few errors with your code which would be great for you to be aware of!

`<style></style>` is meant to be in the `<head></head>` tag.

`<br></br>` [isn't how you use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) the `<br>` element. It self closes, so you can either leave it as `<br>`, or close it yourself with `<br />`. It also shouldn't really be used to increase gaps between content, you should be using the CSS margin or padding properties.

On your `H1` inline styles, `font-family:Segoe UI;60px;text-align:center;`, `60px` isn't doing anything, you need font-size: before it, so that line would be `font-family:Segoe UI;font-size: 60px;text-align:center;`.

The `<marquee>` tag [isn't part of the standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee), and its behaviour is different depending on the browser.

I would also recommend putting all of your css into your `<style>` tag at the top. It makes your HTML a lot cleaner, and using HTML styles is generally bad practice these days!

Oh, and as WP_ said, `<pr>` isn't an element. `<p>` and `<pre>` are though. `<p>` should be used for paragraphs.

Comment: both HTML files and the image are on the same directory,but it's work as i said on _list.html_
Anyway thankyou for the other correction and suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following code within the body tag on both pages to see if the image can be found at all:

```
<img src="Judul.jpg" alt="Judul"/>
```

Is the image visible on both pages?

Have you tried emptying the browser cache and reloaded your pages?

Why are you using `<pr></pr>` tags on the second page? There is no such thing in HTML. It is always a good idea to validate your HTML from time to time: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

Are list.html, your second html file, and Judu1.jpg all in the same directory? You are referencing the image relatively, so it Judu1.jpg would have to be in the same directory as your html file.

Answer (score -1):

Can see u type in some style for the H1 tag and so on, then just do the same for the body.. remove u'r STYLE and replace

```
<body>
```

with

```
<body background="Judul.jpg">
```